# Cruise ship in the Schengen area: How would the following add up

Tags: schengen, cruising

Given the following cruise scenario, how many days would be counted again a Schengen 90 day count?

DAY 1   Southampton **UK**
DAY 2   At **Sea**
DAY 3   Kirkwall, Orkney Islands (**UK**)
DAY 4   Tórshavn Faroe Islands (**Denmark protectorate**)
DAY 5   At **Sea**
DAY 6   Akureyri (**Iceland**)
DAY 7   Isafjörður (**Iceland**)
DAY 8-9 Reykjavik (**Iceland**) overnight
DAY 10-12   At **Sea**
DAY 13  Honningsvåg, **Norway**
DAY 14  Tromsø, **Norway**
DAY 15  Leknes, Lofoten Island (**Norway**)
DAY 16  Narvik (**Norway**)
DAY 17  At **Sea**
DAY 18  Trondheim (**Norway**)
DAY 19  Kristiansund (**Norway**)
DAY 20  Alesund (**Norway**)
DAY 21  Skjolden (**Norway**)
DAY 22-23   At **Sea**
DAY 24  Southampton (**UK**)

I am expecting every day from day 4 through day 21, i.e. first Schengen port to last, but if this can be confirmed I'd be most appreicative as we try to count the days for multiple vacations.

Comment: I don't know whether you'll be stamped in or out of any of those ports, but if so it will be counted according to the stamps.  If not, it might not count at all.

Comment: Hi Alan, if the linked question does not help you, please reply using a comment to explain why, so we can reopen this question.  Thank you.